# How to read Text on any view of any application using AccessibilityInfo?

Tags: android, accessibility

I am trying to read every item inside a ListView of any application by using AccessibilityInfo class. The problem is that i am getting the total number of items inside the ListView by using the following piece of code:

---

```
 if(event.getClassName().equals("android.widget.ListView")) {
            String className= TextView.class.getName();
            AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo= event.getSource();
            int i= nodeInfo.getChildCount(); }
```

---

But i am not getting the names of items inside the ListView , for example let there are 5 textviews inside one ListView then i want to get the text from that TextViews. I tried to further break the nodeInfo object by using:

---

```
 for(int j=0; j<nodeInfo.getChildCount() ;j++){
                AccessibilityNodeInfo subChild = nodeInfo.getChild(j);
                CharSequence subText = subChild.getText();

                Log.e("MyService: ","ListView child name: "+subText);
            }
```

---

So what i am doing wrong in getting the values of TextView's inside ListView ,

or

it is not possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution by myself and the solution is:
**event.getSource()** method returns instance of **AccessibilityNodeInfo** and by converting that instance value to String format we can easily get the results. Just we need is to break the string and get the required result out, in my case the way i did is:

```
 String get_cord= String.valueOf(event.getSource());
    String[] first_split= get_cord.split("[;]");
                    for(int i=0; i<first_split.length; i++){
                        if(first_split[i].contains("text")){
                            String[] second_split= first_split[i].split(":");
                            user= second_split[1].trim();
                            System.out.println(user);
                            Log.e("MyService: ","username is: "+user);

                            break;
                        }
                    }`
```